# Tabbar stopped showing any modifications made to the Tabbar file in Xamarin->Laoyuts

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

new here. I need help figuring out why my xamarin project is not reading any of the changes I make to the Tabbar.xml file. Everything was working fine until I decided to add a splash screen style. It could have been something else but that is the only major change I have done to my project, unless I deleted something i wasn't supposed to. Regardless I will be showing those changes as well. I was thinking of just making a custom renderer to avoid this headache, but not I really am curious why this is occurring. Also the unselected tint color has defaulted to white. I can try to change that on the Tabbar.xml side but it does not update. Only the selectedTabcolor changes but because I set that in the `<TabbedPage></TabbedPage>` itself. All I want is to have the Text color of the unselected tabs to default the grey that the tab icons seem to defult to, that's how it used to be, and set the selectedTabcolor and TabIndicatorColor to the same color which is #008000.
**MainActivity**

```
[Activity(Label = "Weather App", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
           
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        
}
```

**SplashScreen**

```
[Activity(Label = "Weather App", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme ="@style/SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);
            Finish();
        }
 }
```

**Styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
       <item name="colorPrimary">#efefef</item>
        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#008000</item>
        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#019501</item>
    </style>
    <!-- SPLASH SCREEN -->
     <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Tabbar.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#008000"
    />
```

EDIT: As request here is an image of how my tabbar looks like:
[image]

I also removed the SelectedTabColor from the `<TabbedPage>` itself and added on those changes to the Tabbar.xml and this is the result. I can't get the text color, nor the indicator color nor the selected color to change through the Tabbar. I believe my Tabbar.xaml page is just not being read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define the text color in your `Tabbar.xml` in the `Resources/layout/Tabbar.xml` of the androd project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" 
    app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black"   //unselect text color
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#008000"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#008000"
/>
```

and if you set the `UnselectedTabColor` or `SelectedTabColor` in your tabbedpage.xaml,It will overrides the settings in the `Tabbar.xml`.It has nothing to do with the startup page you added.

If your project has migrated to AndroidX,you could install `Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.Resources` and `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design` nugets separately.

Comment: i've tried that as well doesn't seem to like that either

Comment: @MiamiH007 Do you just want to change the `UnselectedTabColor`  and `SelectedTabColor`  ? Or could you show the screenshot of your effect now and the effect which you want to achieve to.

Comment: I added the image of how my app looks like and I removed any modifications I was doing to the TabbedPage directly, just relying on the tabbar.xaml page and it still is not reflecting my changes. and yes I only want to change the color for both the unselectedTabColor and SelectedTabColor

Comment: @MiamiH007 This is rather weird, but it works fine for me to run with your code. What is your version of xamarin.forms? Try deleting the bin and obj files to rebuild.

Comment: I have xamarin.Forms v5.0.0.19. Let me try to remove the bin and try rebuilding. You don't think this would have anything to do with adding the splash screen and adding a theme to it?

Comment: @MiamiH007 I also add the splash screen and a theme,it still works.

Comment: Deleting the bin and obj folder did nothing. Do you suggest I do a custom renderer?

Comment: @MiamiH007 I may have found the reason,as you use Xamarin.Forms v5.0,it reference the androidx library,the `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` is not inside it. You could install the `Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.Resources` and `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design` nuget.Then it could work.You could have a try.

Comment: Thank You! That fixed it. Why would this library not be included?

Comment: @MiamiH007 Because after api 28,`android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` has changed to `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout`,and in the new version of the project,the project has migrated to AndroidX.If this is helpful to you,could you mark it as an accept answer.

Comment: sure, but I wasn't sure how do I mark a comment?